# Plotting by groupby and average

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with multiple columns and rows. One column, say 'name' has several rows with names,  the same name used multiple times. Other rows, say, 'x', 'y', 'z', 'zz' have values. I want to group by name and get the mean of each column (x,y,z,zz)for each name, then plot on a bar chart.

Comment: either `df.groupby('Name').mean().plot(kind='bar')`  or `df.groupby('Name').mean().T.plot(kind='bar')` ?

Comment: Further to your edit: . Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) is an important data-wrangling stuff. Let's first make a dummy Pandas data frame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"name": ["John", "Sansa", "Bran", "John", "Sansa", "Bran"],
                   "x": [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                   "y": [5, -3, 10, 34, 1, 54],
                   "z": [10.6, 99.9, 546.23, 34.12, 65.04, -74.29]})
>>>
        name    x   y   z
   0    John    2   5   10.60
   1    Sansa   3   -3  99.90
   2    Bran    4   10  546.23
   3    John    5   34  34.12
   4    Sansa   6   1   65.04
   5    Bran    7   54  -74.29
```

We can use the label of the column to group the data (here the label is "name"). Explicitly defining the by parameter can be omitted (c.f., `df.groupby("name")`).

```
df.groupby(by = "name").mean().plot(kind = "bar")
```

which gives us a nice bar graph.

[image]

Transposing the group by results using [`T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) (as also suggested by anky) yields a different visualization. We can also pass a dictionary as the by parameter to determine the groups. The by parameter can also be a function, Pandas series, or ndarray.

```
df.groupby(by = {1: "Sansa", 2: "Bran"}).mean().T.plot(kind = "bar")
```

[image]